Encountering 'This ZooKeeper instance is not currently serving requests' while starting zookeeper ensemble
I'm encountering an issue while setting up a 3-node ZooKeeper ensemble (apache zookeeper). When attempting to start ZooKeeper on one of the nodes and issuing the mntr 4-letter command, I'm receiving the error message "This ZooKeeper instance is not currently serving requests." I'm encountering an issue while setting up a 3-node ZooKeeper ensemble. When attempting to start ZooKeeper on one of the nodes and issuing the mntr 4-letter command, I'm receiving the error message "This ZooKeeper instance is not currently serving requests."
Logs from zookeeper (id: 3)
[2024-04-05 17:07:48,758 [myid:3] - INFO  [WorkerReceiver[myid=3]:FastLeaderElection$Messenger$WorkerReceiver@390] - Notification: my state:LOOKING; n.sid:2, n.state:LEADING, n.leader:2, n.round:0x1, n.peerEpoch:0x1, n.zxid:0x0, message format version:0x2, n.config version:0x0
2024-04-05 17:08:03,020 [myid:3] - INFO  [NIOWorkerThread-31:NIOServerCnxn@514] - Processing srvr command from /127.0.0.1:49664
2024-04-05 17:08:48,758 [myid:3] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=3](plain=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0]:2181)(secure=disabled):FastLeaderElection@980] - Notification time out: 60000
2024-04-05 17:08:48,759 [myid:3] - INFO  [WorkerReceiver[myid=3]:FastLeaderElection$Messenger$WorkerReceiver@390] - Notification: my state:LOOKING; n.sid:3, n.state:LOOKING, n.leader:3, n.round:0x1, n.peerEpoch:0x0, n.zxid:0x0, message format version:0x2, n.config version:0x0
2024-04-05 17:08:48,759 [myid:3] - WARN  [QuorumConnectionThread-[myid=3]-33:QuorumCnxManager@401] - Cannot open channel to 1 at election address /<IP of id 1>:3881
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.initiateConnection(QuorumCnxManager.java:384)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager$QuorumConnectionReqThread.run(QuorumCnxManager.java:458)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Logs from working follower (id: 1)
2024-04-05 16:37:54,978 [myid:1] - WARN  [QuorumConnectionThread-[myid=1]-2:QuorumCnxManager@401] - Cannot open channel to 2 at election address /<Ip of id 1>:3881
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.initiateConnection(QuorumCnxManager.java:384)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager$QuorumConnectionReqThread.run(QuorumCnxManager.java:458)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2024-04-05 16:37:58,023 [myid:1] - WARN  [QuorumConnectionThread-[myid=1]-3:QuorumCnxManager@401] - Cannot open channel to 3 at election address /<Ip of id 3>:3881
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.initiateConnection(QuorumCnxManager.java:384)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager$QuorumConnectionReqThread.run(QuorumCnxManager.java:458)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Despite the leader being operational and functioning correctly, the logs indicate occurrences of leader election. What could be causing these leader election events?
I've tried various solutions found online, but none seem to resolve the issue. Can someone please provide insight into why this issue is occurring and how to resolve it? [Leader is ID:2]
Solutions I tried:
I halted the ZooKeeper service on all nodes within the ensemble and initiated the startup process based on each node's ID. Additionally, I verified the configuration settings and reviewed the myid file located in the data directory.
